# processing messages

Tags: wcf, windows-services, msmq

I use a queue per message type. I have tended to create a windows service per queue to process those messages. Is this the best use of resources? I suspect not. How do you decide how many processes should service a queue(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to consider here is service levels. Does all of the data represented by the message types require identical processing service levels? Are some messages more important than others? Do some messages have latency requirement for delivery? Are some messages critical to the business whereas others not? Are the expected volumes of all message types different?

Currently the way you have things set up means that you can manage each of your message type channels as a separate concern, which allows you maximum flexibility to support all possible service level scenarios. However this comes as a cost of higher resource cost/more moving parts.

I would say that unless resource usage is a concern, then your set up is the best possible as you decouple your data processing channels from one another very effectively in this way.